# Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object on line 7

Tags: mysql, database, php

```
<center>
<?php

$lasttime = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] - 3600*24*30; // 1 month
```

Calling to database?

```
$q = $db->query('SELECT * from votes where lasttime > '.$lasttime);
if($q->num_rows>0)
{
$users = array();
while($r = $q->fetch_object())
{
  $users[$r->username] += 1;
}
if(!empty($users))
{
foreach($users as $user => $t)
{
echo"<br /><strong>$user</strong> has voted $t times";
}
}
```

If no votes no vote logs.

```
}else{
echo"NO VOTE LOGS YET";
}


?>
</center>
```

From what I understand it cant log in to the MYSQL Database?
And im not really sure how to do that. 
Thanks!

Comment: If this is your complete code, you have not connected to the database by instantiating `$db = new mysqli('host','user','password','dbname');`

Comment: Are you using a framework or something?

Answer (score 1):

`$db` is not an object, which means the connection failed. You should check if the connection has been established. Assuming you are using mysqli: [read this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php)

Comment: Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user '******'@'site.********.com' (using password: YES) in line 6

Warning: mysqli::query() [mysqli.query]: Couldn't fetch mysqli in on line 7

Comment: <center>
<?php

$lasttime = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] - 3600*24*30; // 1 month
$db = new mysqli('*******','*******','********','votes');
$q = $db->query('SELECT * from votes where lasttime > '.$lasttime);
if($q->num_rows>0)
{
$users = array();
while($r = $q->fetch_object())
{
  $users[$r->username] += 1;
}
if(!empty($users))
{
foreach($users as $user => $t)
{
echo"<br /><strong>$user</strong> has voted $t times";
}
}

}else{
echo"NO VOTE LOGS YET";
}


?>
</center>

Comment: @ilovepie Access denied for user '***'@'site.*****.com' means that you can't connect with that username and password to the specified database.

Answer (score 0):

Add before line 7...

```
$db = new mysqli('host','user','password','dbname');
```